# Flink may recompute records during fault tolerance

Tags: apache-flink

I've read the doc about Flink's checkpointing mechanism from [Data Streaming Fault Tolerance](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/internals/stream_checkpointing.html),
and I wonder how does it ensure the exactly once semantics.
Consider there is a Flink job with checkpoint enabled and the interval of checkpointing is 500ms. If the last completed checkpoint is n and after that, a few records have been computed and then the job failed before the next checkpoint.So are these records will be recomputed after the job recovery.

Comment: Yes, some records will be re-processed during recovery. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43442562/2000823

Comment: I got it,thanks a lot