# What happens if Flink job restarts between two checkpoints?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

This question is basically similar to the one asked here: [Apache Flink fault tolerance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60016537/apache-flink-fault-tolerance).
i.e. what happens if a job restarts between two checkpoints? Will it reprocess the records that were already processed after the last checkpoint?

Take for example I have two jobs, job1 and job2. Job1 consumes records from Kafka, processes them and again produces them to second Kafka topic. Job2 consumes from this second topic and processes the records (in my case its updating values in aerospike using AerospikeClient).

Now from the answer to this question [Apache Flink fault tolerance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60016537/apache-flink-fault-tolerance), I can somehow believe that if job1 restarts, it will not produce duplicates records in the sink. I am using FlinkKafkaProducer011 which extends TwoPhaseCommitSinkFunction (https://flink.apache.org/features/2018/03/01/end-to-end-exactly-once-apache-flink.html). Please explain how it will prevent reprocessing (ie duplicate production of records to Kafka).

According to Flink doc, flink restarts a job from last successful checkpoint. So if job2 restarts before completing the checkpoint, it will restart from last checkpoint and the records that were already processed after that last checkpoint will be reprocessed (ie multiple updations in aerospike).
Am I right or is there something else in Flink (& aerospike) that prevents this reprocessing in job2?

Answer (score 1):

In such a scenario, Flink will indeed reprocess some events. During recovery the input partitions will have their offsets reset to the offsets in the most recent checkpoint, and events that had been read after that checkpoint will be re-ingested.

However, the `FlinkKafkaProducer` uses Kafka transactions that are committed when checkpoints are completed. When a job fails, whatever output it has produced since the last checkpoint is protected by transactions that are never committed. So long as that job's consumers are configured to use `read_committed` as their `isolation.level`, they won't see any duplicates.

For more details, see [Best Practices for Using Kafka Sources/Sinks in Flink Jobs](https://ververica.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360013269680).

Comment: Hi david, Thanks fo the ans. Correct me if I'm wrong, by setting "semantic = EXACTLY_ONCE" in Kafka producer of job1, I am making sure that records will be committed after the checkpoint is completed. And by setting "isolation.level = read_committed", in consumer of job2, only committed records will be consumed.
**Also I have another question, will there be some impact on performance/throughput? If my checkpoint interval is 5s, then the records between two checkpoints (for 5sec) will not be consumed by job2, as they would not have been committed.**

Comment: Also this only guarantee exactly once until job1 produces into Kafka. But in a scenario if job2 crashes between 2 checkpoints, there would still be re-processing. (Job2 has no sink, it is just updating aerospike). How can I solve that?

Comment: How is the data getting into aerospike?

Comment: We have extended RichMapFunction in which we recieve the records from kafka and store/update a record in aerospike based upon some key.
**aerospikeClient.put(writePolicy, aeroKey, new Bin("value", kafkaRecord))**
We do not want to update the same record more than once in any case